# Probability - Calculate E[y] given that you know the conditional density of Y given X = x

Tags: probability, probability-theory, actuarial-science

**The problem states:**

> X is a continuous uniform random variable on [0,50].
>
> The conditional distribution of Y given X=x follows a uniform distribution  on [0,15x].
>
> Calculate E[y].

From this, we know the marginal density of x is $\frac {1}{15x}$.

But how do we find E[y]? I try to use the double expectation formula, E[Y] = E[E[Y|X]], but that's not the right approach.

I have spent over two days trying to solve this problem and I keep running into a brick wall. If anyone can help steer me in the right direction, I would greatly appreciate it.

The correct answer is 187.5. Thanks

Comment: Why do you say that $\mathbb{E}[Y]=\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[Y\mid X]]$ is not the right approach?

Comment: Maybe it is the right approach? Working the inside first, E[Y|X = x] a integral from 0 to 50 of y/15x dy, which gives (250/3)*(1/x). Then I'm not sure how to set up the outer integral.

Comment: You should get $\mathbb{E}[Y\mid X=x]=\frac{15x}{2}$, and then integrate this from $0$ to $50$ and divide by $50$.

Comment: I was doing the limits incorrectly. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your approach seems ok to me: $E(Y|X)=15X/2$, and then calculate $E(15X/2)$.